# trying to .push from inside of a function to the outside and/or trying to make my function spit out a single line in console.log

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I am doing this assignment:

> Write a function named snapCrackle that takes one parameter: maxValue.
> This function should loop through 1 up to maxValue (inclusive) and
> build a string with the following conditions: If a number is odd,
> concatenate "Snap, " to the end of the string. If a number is a
> multiple of 5, concatenate "Crackle, " to the end of the string. If a
> number is both odd and a multiple of 5 concatenate "SnapCrackle, " to
> the end of the string. If a number is neither odd or a multiple of 5,
> concatenate the number and ", " to the end of the string. This
> function should console.log() the final string after maxValue
> iterations of the loop.

This is my solution:

```
let c = "Snap, ";
let i = "Crackle, ";
let x = "SnapCrackle, ";
let b = ",";
let maxValue = 20;
let counter = 1;
let output = "";
let list = ["snap", "crackle", "snapCrackle"];
function snapCrackle() {
  while (counter <= maxValue) {
    if (counter % 5 === 0 && counter % 2 !== 0) {
      console.log(x + counter);
    } else if (counter % 5 === 0) {
      console.log(i + counter);
    } else if (counter % 5 === 0 || counter % 2 !== 1) {
      console.log(counter + b);
    } else if (counter % 2 !== 0) {
      console.log(c + counter);
    }
    counter++;
  }
}
console.log();
return snapCrackle();
let results = " ";
console.log(snapCrackle());
```

I was told:

> Great start! You have everything you need, but it should be a single
> string. For Snap, Crackle, and SnapCrackle, you shouldn't display the
> number next to it, although I appreciate the cleverness and effort of
> it. A hint I will give for solving this is creating an empty string
> and concatenating the results to it!

How do I push my counter to an array so I can `console.log` a single line, or how can I make the function itself output a single line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have done all the hard-work. Small changes and you are good with your answer.

```
let c = "Snap";
let i = "Crackle";
let x = "SnapCrackle";
let maxValue = 20;
let counter = 1;
// let output = ""; // not required rather use an array
// let list = ["snap", "crackle", "snapCrackle"]; // not required
let outPutArr = [];
function snapCrackle() {
  while (counter <= maxValue) {
    if (counter % 5 === 0 && counter % 2 !== 0) {
      outPutArr.push(x);
    } else if (counter % 5 === 0) {
      outPutArr.push(i);
    } else if (counter % 5 === 0 || counter % 2 !== 1) {
      outPutArr.push(counter);
    } else if (counter % 2 !== 0) {
      outPutArr.push(c);
    }
    counter++;
  }
  return outPutArr // return the created array from conditions 
}
console.log(snapCrackle().join()); // Return the join of the array
```